# Ruby method undefined for nilClass errors for string methods

Tags: ruby, regex, string, file-io

I don't understand why the below doesn't work:

```
#TODO:
#Open file-io-samples/MultipleLinesCustomDelimiter.txt
#Break each line into fields
#Convert Times from mm:ss to seconds
#Remove any redundant spaces.
#######################################################

Song = Struct.new(:title, :name, :length)

File.open("file-io-samples/MultipleLinesCustomDelimiter.txt") do |file_data|
  songs = []
  file_data.each do |line|
    file, length, name, title =  line.chomp.split(/\s*\|\s*/)
    name.squeeze!(" ") #Error: undefined method for nilClass
    mins, secs = length.scan(/\d+/) #Error: undefined method for nilClass
    secs += mins*60
    songs << Song.new(title, name, secs)
  end
  puts songs[1] #make sure output is consistent.
end
```

Contents of the file that's being read:

```
/jazz/j00132.mp3 | 3:45 | Fats Waller | Ain't Misbehavin'
/jazz/j00319.mp3 | 2:58 | Louis Armstrong | Wonderful World
/bgrass/bg0732.mp3| 4:09 | Strength in Numbers | Texas Red
: : : :
```

This is an example from the Programming Ruby book. I dont know why the scan method and squeeze method throw errors when they are string objects not nilClass objects. Without these the output from puts songs[1] looks correct.

Comment: They say they are `nilClass`, not `String`.

Comment: I know that, but I don't understand how they can't be string.

Answer (score 3):

The last row

> : : : :

doesn't match the split, so name, length and title are nil

file ends up as

> : : : :

A parallel example:

```
a,b,c = [1,2]
#a=1
#b=2
#c = nil
```

Comment: Ahh, I meant to use that to detect the end of the file. What an oversight on my part. Thank you for your assistance. I'll mark the answer after the cooldown.

Comment: You're welcome, unfortunately there's not a lot of context with the exceptions so it's a matter of using strategic puts statements or the debugger.

Comment: Yea, that was a pretty simple mistake on my part.